# Install the ipython ImportError: No module named pickleshare

Tags: python, ipython

Today,I have installed the ipython by the follow steps:

```
cd
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
cd ipython
sudo python setup.py install
```

But I meet a error when I open the ipython:

```
~$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pickleshare import PickleShareDB
ImportError: No module named pickleshare
```

How to deal with the error?

Comment: If you replace `python setup.py install` with `pip install .`, dependencies should be installed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that `pickleshare` is in package `IPython.utils`.

Use this `pip install -I path.py==7.7.1`

Updating the package to `version 8.1` should fix the problem as well now:

`pip install -I path.py==8.1`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to use your approach, but it occured an error.Then I remove the Cpython on my computer and delete all the files about the Cpython.I installed the Cpython agin by the approach:$sudo apt-get install Cpython Furtunately, I was successful.But I don't know why it be failed when I use the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with sudo easy_install pickleshare
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pickleshare/0.3)